# Collapsing column in a prop.table

Tags: r

I have this prop.table (created with `questionr::lprop`):

```
    COMSAL
orig      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10  Total
  10  38.31  24.11   6.85   6.45   2.58   3.98   8.72   3.98   1.69   3.32 100.00
  11  34.20  30.22   6.01   9.64   2.36   3.08   2.73   4.44   2.36   4.95 100.00
  14  37.15  30.12   4.89   8.53   3.11   3.05   2.99   3.54   3.22   3.41 100.00
  15  39.67  30.77   6.00   4.54   1.72   1.86   3.09   5.46   2.41   4.48 100.00
  21  36.52  27.27  10.12   3.71   3.65   2.10   6.92   2.96   3.21   3.54 100.00
  22  34.63  27.77   8.99   5.11   2.89   2.78   5.75   7.21   2.36   2.50 100.00
```

I'd like to sum from column 3 to 10 to get this desired output:

```
    COMSAL
orig      1      2    SUM   Total
  10  38.31  24.11   37.6   100.00
  11  34.20  30.22   35.6   100.00
  14  37.15  30.12   32.7   100.00
  15  39.67  30.77   29.6   100.00
  21  36.52  27.27   36.2   100.00
  22  34.63  27.77   37.6   100.00
```

Currently I use some sort of combination with dplyr but it's really long and I wonder if there is a built-in package/function that can do that.

**DATA**

```
structure(c(38.31, 34.2, 37.15, 39.67, 36.52, 34.63, 24.11, 30.22, 
30.12, 30.77, 27.27, 27.77, 6.85, 6.01, 4.89, 6, 10.12, 8.99, 
6.45, 9.64, 8.53, 4.54, 3.71, 5.11, 2.58, 2.36, 3.11, 1.72, 3.65, 
2.89, 3.98, 3.08, 3.05, 1.86, 2.1, 2.78, 8.72, 2.73, 2.99, 3.09, 
6.92, 5.75, 3.98, 4.44, 3.54, 5.46, 2.96, 7.21, 1.69, 2.36, 3.22, 
2.41, 3.21, 2.36, 3.32, 4.95, 3.41, 4.48, 3.54, 2.5, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100), .Dim = c(6L, 11L), .Dimnames = list(orig = c("10", 
"11", "14", "15", "21", "22"), COMSAL = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Total")), class = "table")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. `base` R solution

```
cbind(x[, 1:2], rowSums(x[, 3:10]), x[, 11])
```

---

#### 2. `dplyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)

as.data.frame.matrix(x) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(SUM = sum(c_across(`3`:`10`)), .keep = "unused") %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#     `1`   `2` Total   SUM
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  38.3  24.1   100  37.6
# 2  34.2  30.2   100  35.6
# 3  37.2  30.1   100  32.7
# 4  39.7  30.8   100  29.6
# 5  36.5  27.3   100  36.2
# 6  34.6  27.8   100  37.6
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is `Reduce`

```
cbind(df1[, 1:2], Reduce(`+`, asplit(df1[, 3:10], 2)), df1[, 11])
```